# JPA replace one element in a collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring data jpa. I have a one to many relationship defined as so:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "participant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<SurveyResponse> getSurveyResponses() {
        return surveyResponses;
    }
```

I have a method that takes a collection of surveyResponses and replaces existing repsonses that have a matching key. Unfortunately, when I use it, hibernate deletes all responses other than the ones I'm adding. Why is that happening?

I never save responses directly, I just set them in the collection and let cascade do the rest. Here is the method that does the replacement:

```
public void updateResponses(List<SurveyResponse> responses) {
        for (SurveyResponse response : responses) {
            response.setParticipant(this);
        }
        if (this.surveyResponses != null) {
            Set<String> questionKeys = responses.stream()
                    .map(SurveyResponse::getQuestionKey)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            this.surveyResponses.removeIf(
                    surveyResponse -> questionKeys.contains(surveyResponse.getQuestionKey()));
            this.surveyResponses.addAll(responses);
        } else this.surveyResponses = responses;
    }
```

After the addAll call the PersistentBag has a mix of old (managed) and new (not yet persisted) responses. When I call save (spring data jpa crudRepository method) on the participant entity, all old responses are deleted. Why?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that not everything is getting removed from the collection after removeIf()? Yes! you mentioned it but did you really see if in debugger that you indeed still have some attached responses after removeIf()?

Comment: Yes, I ran this in the debugger, I watched as the PersistentBag got one element smaller after the removeIf, it got one element larger after the addAll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question should be deleted, as it was a bug elsewhere in my code. I made an overcomplicated setter that was causing the issue.  Deleting questions with answers is discouraged so I'm just answering my own question here. For anyone's curiosity, this was the bad setter:

```
 public void setSurveyResponses(List<SurveyResponse> surveyResponses) {
    if (this.surveyResponses == null) {
        this.surveyResponses = surveyResponses;
    } else {
        this.surveyResponses.clear();
        if (surveyResponses != null) {
            this.surveyResponses.addAll(surveyResponses);
        }
    }
    if (this.surveyResponses != null) {
        for (SurveyResponse response : this.surveyResponses) {
            response.setParticipant(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Note to self, setters are for hibernate to use, not for your own code. If you need a fancy setter, make a new method.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the cause of your problem:
http://assarconsulting.blogspot.com/2009/08/why-hibernate-does-delete-all-then-re.html

I would suggest replacing the collection type from `List` to `Set` and see how that behaves.

Comment: I'd be happy if hibernate did a delete all  and reinsert of everything in the collection in memory, but it is only inserting what I added to the collection and failing to reinsert the elements I didn't touch

Comment: I actually changed it to use Set for fun but it didn't make a difference. I'm guessing the issue is that I am breaking the rule : "A managed object should only ever reference other managed objects, and a detached object should only reference other detached objects. Avoid relating or mixing detached and managed objects, this will normally lead to issues, as your application could access two copies of the same object causing loss of changes or stale data ." mentioned here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Persisting#Detached_vs_Managed